# How to do ANOVA with three categorical variables?

Tags: r, anova

I want to carry on three-way anova on my datasets. My datasets contain three factors, including rank (3 levels), population (2 levels) and type (2 levels). 
What is did is that I first ran a anova with afex

```
    aov_rossie <- aov_car(wtp ~ rank * type * population + Error(id) , d1)

Anova Table (Type 3 tests)

Response: wtp
                Effect     df   MSE         F  ges p.value
1                 rank 2, 228 26.90 34.28 ***  .23  <.0001
2                 type 1, 228 26.90      0.34 .001     .56
3           population 1, 228 26.90      1.98 .009     .16
4            rank:type 2, 228 26.90      0.50 .004     .60
5      rank:population 2, 228 26.90    3.32 *  .03     .04
6      type:population 1, 228 26.90    4.11 *  .02     .04
7 rank:type:population 2, 228 26.90  7.33 ***  .06   .0008
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘+’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and this is what I get, I found that there are 3 significant interaction effect.

But this where I got stuck, I am not really sure in how to do the follow-up test, the code below is what I have tried, but the result looks quiet abnormal

```
    em1 <- emmeans(a3,c("rank","type","population"))
em1 %>%
  pairs() %>%
  update(by = NULL) %>%
  summary(adjust = "holm")


contrast                                                estimate   SE  df t.ratio p.value
 high,absolute,economists - low,absolute,economists         11.20 1.64 228  6.828  <.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - medium,absolute,economists       6.85 1.64 228  4.176  0.0023 
 high,absolute,economists - high,relative,economists         3.80 1.64 228  2.317  0.7706 
 high,absolute,economists - low,relative,economists         10.35 1.64 228  6.310  <.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - medium,relative,economists       6.80 1.64 228  4.146  0.0026 
 high,absolute,economists - high,absolute,general            8.00 1.64 228  4.877  0.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - low,absolute,general             8.85 1.64 228  5.396  <.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - medium,absolute,general          8.10 1.64 228  4.938  0.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - high,relative,general            2.25 1.64 228  1.372  1.0000 
 high,absolute,economists - low,relative,general            10.80 1.64 228  6.584  <.0001 
 high,absolute,economists - medium,relative,general          6.65 1.64 228  4.054  0.0037 
 low,absolute,economists - medium,absolute,economists       -4.35 1.64 228 -2.652  0.3596 
 low,absolute,economists - high,relative,economists         -7.40 1.64 228 -4.512  0.0006 
 low,absolute,economists - low,relative,economists          -0.85 1.64 228 -0.518  1.0000 
 low,absolute,economists - medium,relative,economists       -4.40 1.64 228 -2.683  0.3450 
 low,absolute,economists - high,absolute,general            -3.20 1.64 228 -1.951  1.0000 
 low,absolute,economists - low,absolute,general             -2.35 1.64 228 -1.433  1.0000 
 low,absolute,economists - medium,absolute,general          -3.10 1.64 228 -1.890  1.0000 
 low,absolute,economists - high,relative,general            -8.95 1.64 228 -5.456  <.0001 
 low,absolute,economists - low,relative,general             -0.40 1.64 228 -0.244  1.0000 
 low,absolute,economists - medium,relative,general          -4.55 1.64 228 -2.774  0.2758 
 medium,absolute,economists - high,relative,economists      -3.05 1.64 228 -1.859  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - low,relative,economists        3.50 1.64 228  2.134  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - medium,relative,economists    -0.05 1.64 228 -0.030  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - high,absolute,general          1.15 1.64 228  0.701  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - low,absolute,general           2.00 1.64 228  1.219  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - medium,absolute,general        1.25 1.64 228  0.762  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,economists - high,relative,general         -4.60 1.64 228 -2.804  0.2573 
 medium,absolute,economists - low,relative,general           3.95 1.64 228  2.408  0.6226 
 medium,absolute,economists - medium,relative,general       -0.20 1.64 228 -0.122  1.0000 
 high,relative,economists - low,relative,economists          6.55 1.64 228  3.993  0.0045 
 high,relative,economists - medium,relative,economists       3.00 1.64 228  1.829  1.0000 
 high,relative,economists - high,absolute,general            4.20 1.64 228  2.561  0.4438 
 high,relative,economists - low,absolute,general             5.05 1.64 228  3.079  0.1120 
 high,relative,economists - medium,absolute,general          4.30 1.64 228  2.622  0.3830 
 high,relative,economists - high,relative,general           -1.55 1.64 228 -0.945  1.0000 
 high,relative,economists - low,relative,general             7.00 1.64 228  4.268  0.0016 
 high,relative,economists - medium,relative,general          2.85 1.64 228  1.738  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - medium,relative,economists       -3.55 1.64 228 -2.164  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - high,absolute,general            -2.35 1.64 228 -1.433  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - low,absolute,general             -1.50 1.64 228 -0.914  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - medium,absolute,general          -2.25 1.64 228 -1.372  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - high,relative,general            -8.10 1.64 228 -4.938  0.0001 
 low,relative,economists - low,relative,general              0.45 1.64 228  0.274  1.0000 
 low,relative,economists - medium,relative,general          -3.70 1.64 228 -2.256  0.8762 
 medium,relative,economists - high,absolute,general          1.20 1.64 228  0.732  1.0000 
 medium,relative,economists - low,absolute,general           2.05 1.64 228  1.250  1.0000 
 medium,relative,economists - medium,absolute,general        1.30 1.64 228  0.793  1.0000 
 medium,relative,economists - high,relative,general         -4.55 1.64 228 -2.774  0.2758 
 medium,relative,economists - low,relative,general           4.00 1.64 228  2.439  0.5893 
 medium,relative,economists - medium,relative,general       -0.15 1.64 228 -0.091  1.0000 
 high,absolute,general - low,absolute,general                0.85 1.64 228  0.518  1.0000 
 high,absolute,general - medium,absolute,general             0.10 1.64 228  0.061  1.0000 
 high,absolute,general - high,relative,general              -5.75 1.64 228 -3.506  0.0269 
 high,absolute,general - low,relative,general                2.80 1.64 228  1.707  1.0000 
 high,absolute,general - medium,relative,general            -1.35 1.64 228 -0.823  1.0000 
 low,absolute,general - medium,absolute,general             -0.75 1.64 228 -0.457  1.0000 
 low,absolute,general - high,relative,general               -6.60 1.64 228 -4.024  0.0041 
 low,absolute,general - low,relative,general                 1.95 1.64 228  1.189  1.0000 
 low,absolute,general - medium,relative,general             -2.20 1.64 228 -1.341  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,general - high,relative,general            -5.85 1.64 228 -3.567  0.0220 
 medium,absolute,general - low,relative,general              2.70 1.64 228  1.646  1.0000 
 medium,absolute,general - medium,relative,general          -1.45 1.64 228 -0.884  1.0000 
 high,relative,general - low,relative,general                8.55 1.64 228  5.213  <.0001 
 high,relative,general - medium,relative,general             4.40 1.64 228  2.683  0.3450 
 low,relative,general - medium,relative,general             -4.15 1.64 228 -2.530  0.4710 

P value adjustment: holm method for 66 tests
```

Is this the correct way in doing this three-way anova analysis?

Comment: Look at the vignettes that come with the **emmeans** package. There are lots of examples. It looks like you could use a `by` variable, e.g., `pairs(em1, by = c("rank","type"))`, or `pairs(em1, simple = "each")`